# How do I programatically set the values (plural) of a multi-select box element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/cgi_info.py" method="POST">
  <select id="faults" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="faults[]">
    <option>Big nose
    <option>Big feet
    <option>Wrinkly nose
    <option>Wrinkly feet
    <option>Spotty nose
    <option>Spotty feet
  </select>
</form>
```

And want to select, for example, all those options containing the text 'nose' using a span tag onclick event around some text.

Can you help me with the onclick javascript code?

Thanks.

Comment: consider using jquery perhaps? makes things easier

Comment: Hi K, I did look into using such libraries but decided to use the "raw" javascript/HTML for this as I am new to web development and find that I gain more by having some insight into the "bare metal". Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to iterate over the `<option>` elements, check the contents and set the `selected` property accordingly:

```
var faults = document.getElementById("faults").options,
    reg = /\bnose\b/;

for (var i=0, max = faults.length; i < max; i++) {
    faults[i].selected = reg.test(faults[i].innerHTML);
}
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gPQ7U/**

Comment: Thanks Andy. jsfiddle is just what I needed to adapt your solution to my real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

`<form action="/cgi-bin/cgi_info.py" method="POST">
  <select id="faults" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="faults[]">
    <option>Big nose
    <option>Big feet
    <option>Wrinkly nose
    <option>Wrinkly feet
    <option>Spotty nose
    <option>Spotty feet
  </select>
</form>`

`<script>`
`function search(){
    for (i=0; i <= document.getElementById('faults').options.length - 1; i++){
        if (document.getElementById('faults').options[i].text.indexOf('nose') > 0) {
            alert(document.getElementById('faults').options[i].text);`
        }
    }
}
 `</script>`

`<input type="button" value="Find by text" onclick="search();"></input>`

Comment: Thanks for your time Lucian, It's appreciated.