# Set Selected Indices in Multi Select Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, multi-select

Im not sure why this isnt working and would love some help with it!  And yes i have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957493/how-do-i-programatically-set-the-values-plural-of-a-multi-select-box-element-u)

Im trying to set multiple options in a select element as selected using an array holding the values i want selected and interating through both the array and the options in the select element.    Please find code below:

```
// value is the array.
for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].text == value[j]) {
            el[i].selected = true;
            alert("option should be selected");
        }
    }
}
```

After completing these loops nothing is selected, even though the alert() fires.

Any ideas are welcome!

Thanks

CM

PS (not sure whats happened to the code formatting).

EDIT: Full function

```
    if (CheckVariableIsArray(value) == true) {
        if (value.length > 1) { // Multiple selections are made, not just a sinle one.
            var checkBoxEl = document.getElementById(cbxElement);
            checkBoxEl.checked = "checked";
            checkBoxEl.onchange(); // Call function to change element to a multi select
            document.getElementById(element).onchange(); // Repopulates elements with a new option list.
            for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
                for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
                    if (el[i].text === value[j]) {
                        el[i].selected = true;
                        i = el.length + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            //document.getElementById(element).onchange();
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
            if (el[i].innerHTML == value) {
                el.selectedIndex = i;
                document.getElementById(element).onchange();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Are you setting el and value correctly? And are you sure you want to look at each option's innerHTML instead of it's value attribute?

See the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RtRBY/)**.

---

**HTML:**

```
<select id="pick_me" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
var value = ['Foo', 'Bar'],
    el = document.getElementById("pick_me");

// value is the array.
for (var j = 0; j < value.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        if (el[i].innerHTML == value[j]) {
            el[i].selected = true;
            //alert("option should be selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point about the innerHTML!  Still not working, and its driving me insane!

Comment: `.innerHTML` or `.text` doesn't matter in my example - both work. `.text` is still not getting the option's value attribute if that was your intended purpose. Pastebin your full code.

Comment: Not really. There is still missing code. For example, where does `value` come from and where does `el` come from. I suggest you place some `console.log(...)`s throughout the function and verify each value is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you must set the html select control multiple property, something like this "<select multiple="multiple">...</select>", and then you can use the javascript function SetMultiSelect (defined as below) to set the select html control:

```
function SetMultiSelect(multiSltCtrl, values)
{
    //here, the 1th param multiSltCtrl is a html select control or its jquery object, and the 2th param values is an array
    var $sltObj = $(multiSltCtrl) || multiSltCtrl;
    var opts = $sltObj[0].options; //
    for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++)
    {
        opts[i].selected = false;//don't miss this sentence
        for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
        {
            if (opts[i].value == values[j])
            {
                opts[i].selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $sltObj.multiselect("refresh");//don't forget to refresh!
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    SetMultiSelect($sltCourse,[0,1,2,3]);
});
```

Comment: $sltObj.multiselect doesn't exist  multiselect function

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this question and wasn't satisfied with the answers.
Here's a generic, non-jQuery version. It utilises `Array.indexOf` where possible, but falls back to a foreach loop if it isn't available.

Pass a node into the function, alongside an array of values. Will throw an exception if an invalid element is passed into it. This uses `===` to check against the value. For the most part, make sure you're comparing the option's value to an array of strings.

E.g. `selectValues( document.getElementById( 'my_select_field' ), [ '1', '2', '3'] );`

```
var selectValues = (function() {

    var inArray = ( function() {

        var returnFn;

        if( typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === "function" ) {

            returnFn = function(option, values) {

                return values.indexOf( option.value ) !== -1;

            };

        } else {

            returnFn = function(option, values) {

                var i;

                for( i = 0; i < values.length; i += 1 ) {

                    if( values[ i ] === option.value ) {

                        return true;

                    }

                }

                return false;

            }

        }

        return returnFn;

    }() );

    return function selectValues(elem, values) {

        var 
            i,
            option;

        if( typeof elem !== "object" || typeof elem.nodeType === "undefined" )
            throw 'selectValues() expects a DOM Node as it\'s first parameter, ' + ( typeof elem ) + ' given.';

        if( typeof elem.options === "undefined" ) 
            throw 'selectValues() expects a <select> node with options as it\'s first parameter.';

        for( i = 0; i < elem.options.length; i += 1 ) {

            option = elem.options[ i ];

            option.selected = inArray( option, values );

        }

    }

}());
```